# Dynamics CRM 365: action was not created properly

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to create an action in Dynamics CRM 365.

I can see it on Plugin Registration Tool (as a message), but when I'm trying to call it, it says:

> Resource not found for the segment ...

then I looked it up at the Metadata and I saw that the action was created only with its prefix as `new_`

[image]

I tried below steps:

1. iisreset
2. crm services restart

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. An `Action` has a Display Name and and Internal Name (like a CRM Entity field). The Internal Name will always have the publisher prefix (in your case "new_")

Answer (score 1):

This must be an intermittent Product issue. IISRESET or Async services restart won't help in your case.

Also you didn't mention where you checked the metadata or how/where you are calling this Action.

Btw, only for Actions, CRM is creating dupe entries in Processes. Check this in Adv.Find to verify if you have multiple versions of same Action.

Do these steps:
1. Check the exact Schema name (new_DeleteThisAction or whatever case sensitive name) & call it in webapi, this should work
2. Idenify the dupes if any & delete it
3. Please deactivate/delete the action & activate/create it again if nothing above helps